# Difficulty to plot legend for a color bar in python 3.6

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend

I have 3 colors (ccc) for 3 different types of rock (d2) and I would like to plot a legend with rectangles for my color bar. I already searched about it, but couldn't find the right code. Could you help me?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {'Porosity': [20, 5, 15, 7, 30], 'Permeability': [2500, 100, 110, 40, 
2200], 'Lithology': ['Sandstone', 'Shale', 'Shale', 'Halite', 'Sandstone'], 
'Depth': [1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

d2 = {'Sandstone': 1, 'Shale': 2, 'Halite': 3}

lito = df['Lithology']
df['Label'] = lito.map(d2)

ccc = ['darkgreen','skyblue', 'yellow']
cmap_facies = colors.ListedColormap(ccc[0:len(ccc)], 'indexed')

cluster = np.repeat(np.expand_dims(df['Label'].values, 1), 1, 1)

f, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(2,12))

depth = df['Depth']

ax.imshow(cluster, interpolation='none', aspect='auto', cmap=cmap_facies, 
vmin=1, vmax=3, extent=[0,1 ,np.max(depth),np.min(depth)])

plt.tick_params(bottom=False, labelbottom=False)
```

Comment: Firstly add `plt.legend()` as the last line and see what you get in the legend box. Then, if it still doesn't work, please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: When I add plt.legend(), I get "No handles with labels found to put in legend". I edited the code for a simpler example. Thanks, @Sheldore

Comment: Hi could answer my question in here? Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64295970/create-vertical-stacked-bar-chart-referenced-to-y-values-lithology-stratigraphi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want three legend handles, one for each colored stone. This can be done by adding custom legend handles using `mpatches`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches # <-- Add this import

# Your code here

hands = []
for k, col in zip(d2.keys(), ccc):
    hands.append(mpatches.Patch(color=col, label=k))
plt.legend(handles=hands, loc=(1.05, 0.5), fontsize=18)
```

[image]