# Create vertical stacked bar chart referenced to y values (lithology/stratigraphic column)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'd like to make a stacked bar chart where:

```
y axis : md litho
x axis : litho
```

The data:

[image]

I already tried to make it, using the code that I modified a little from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56496369/difficulty-to-plot-legend-for-a-color-bar-in-python-3-6/56499821#56499821) on stackoverflow.

```
path = pd.ExcelFile('F:\Backup\JN\Litologi\lito.xlsx')
data = pd.read_excel(path)
lito = data['litho']
d2 = {'ABT': 1, 'AT': 2, 'BAT': 3, 'BTT':4, 'GT':5, 'NC':6, 'TT':7}
litocode = lito.map(d2)

ccc = ['firebrick','red', 'peru', 'salmon', 'maroon', 'ghostwhite','pink']
cmap_facies = colors.ListedColormap(ccc[0:len(ccc)], 'indexed')

cluster = np.repeat(np.expand_dims(litocode.values, 1), 1, 1)
print(cluster)
f, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(1,5))

depth = data['md litho']

ax.imshow(cluster, interpolation='none', aspect='auto', cmap=cmap_facies, 
vmin=1, vmax=7, extent=[0,7 ,np.max(depth),np.min(depth)])

plt.tick_params(bottom=False, labelbottom=False)

hands = []
for k, col in zip(d2.keys(), ccc):
    hands.append(mpatches.Patch(color=col, label=k))
plt.legend(handles=hands, loc=(1.05, 0.5), fontsize=12)
```

The code above resulted a figure below. But I notice that the y-axis is divided evenly (0 - 442) into 7 data clusters, based on the number of data in the litho column, but without considering the y-values (md litho).

[image]

So the question is: how to make a figure look like above but with this kind of interval where each interval is blocked/filled by a particular color:

```
Interval = key (color)
0-31 = NC (ghostwhite)
31-49 = AT (red)
49-67 = BTT (salmon)
67-406 = NC (ghostwhite)
406-427 = ABT (firebrick)
427-442 = BAT (peru)
```

Whenever I have data in excel like below,

[image]

where the litho data group (md, elev, litho) is shorter or less compared to the other columns that has the longest rows in the file (the mbt data group in this case) it shows:

```
ValueError: x and y arguments to pcolormesh cannot have non-finite values or be of type numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray with masked values
```

I think somehow the script read the entire column of litho data group up to the max row following the mbt data group even it has nothing.

What could I do to solve that problem?
I already tried to move the data to the other columns but it does not work.
I also tried to masked the values using this script that I read in [pcolormesh with missing values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778343/pcolormesh-with-missing-values) but it still does not work.

```
Z=well['litho'][:-1].map(lithcode).to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)
Zm = ma.array(Z,mask=np.isnan(Z))
cl.pcolormesh([0, 1], well['elev litho'], Zm, cmap=cmap, vmin=1, vmax=len(colors))
```

Comment: @JohanC sorry for the confusion, I already edit the post. Hope it helps you understand the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Masking might not work, but you could just leave out the empty part? Something like `num = np.count_nonzero(~np.isnan(well['litho']))` and then use `z = df['litho'][:num-1].map(d2).to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)` and `y = well['elev litho'][:num]`?

Comment: hi @JohanC thanks for the insight, it works with little modification here
`Zb=well['litho'][:-1].map(lithcode).to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)
                  nonan=np.count_nonzero(Zb[np.logical_not(np.isnan(Zb))])
                  Za=well['litho'][:nonan-1].map(lithcode).to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)
                  Y=well['elev litho'][:nonan]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `pcolormesh` is a mesh of rectangles, where individual heights can be assigned to rows (and columns). The first parameter of `pcolormesh` are the mesh borders on the x-axis, the second for the y-axis.  Such a mesh needs one row and one column more than there are values, so 2 in the x-direction and 7 in the y-direction for a `1x6` mesh.

The values need to be stored in a matrix (the third parameter). To create the matrix, the following steps are taken:

- `df['litho']` is the list of strings
- `[:-1]` takes all elements except the last
- `.map(d2)` maps the strings to numbers
- `.to_numpy()` converts to pandas series to a numpy array
- `.reshape(-1, 1)` converts the 1D array to a 2D array, where the number of rows is equal to the length of the 1D array (`-1` means: the number needed to make the 1D and 2D array have the same number of elements) and the number of columns is 1

Note that `vmin` and `vmax` need to be set explicitly because not all possible values are present in the matrix.

For the figure size, it's easier to use the [object-oriented interface](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/matplotlib/matplotlib_object_oriented_interface.htm), using `fig` and `ax` instead of `plt.`.  `fig, ax = plt.subplots(...)` allows to set the size, and can also create multiple subplots.

Apart from the figure size, also the aspect ratio of 'ax' (the inner plot) can be set. In the example below, an aspect ratio of `0.01` is used, which means the 442 units in the y-axis will occupy the same number of pixels as 100 times the 1 unit on the x-axis.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'md litho': [0, 31, 49, 67, 406, 427, 442],
                   'litho': ['NC', 'AT', 'BTT', 'NC', 'ABT', 'BAT', 'NC']})

d2 = {'ABT': 1, 'AT': 2, 'BAT': 3, 'BTT': 4, 'GT': 5, 'NC': 6, 'TT': 7}
colors = ['firebrick', 'red', 'peru', 'salmon', 'maroon', 'ghostwhite', 'pink']
cmap = ListedColormap(colors)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4))
ax.pcolormesh([0, 1], df['md litho'], df['litho'][:-1].map(d2).to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1),
              cmap=cmap, vmin=1, vmax=len(colors))
ax.set_xticks([])  # hide ticks on the x-axis
ax.set_yticks(df['md litho'])  # optionally set the y-ticks to indicate the row borders
ax.set_aspect(0.01)
hands = [Patch(color=col, label=k) for k, col in zip(d2.keys(), colors)]
ax.legend(handles=hands, bbox_to_anchor=(1.03, 1.02), loc='upper left', fontsize=12, facecolor='lightgrey')
plt.tight_layout()  # this fits the legend and the labels nicely into the figure
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

PS: Use `ax.invert_yaxis()` to have zero at the top.

Comment: one more thing, how could I change the figure size?

Comment: I updated the answer to set the size of the surrounding figure and/or setting the aspect ratio of the `ax`.  I also updated the way the legend is positioned (anchoring it at its upper left corner instead of the default lower left).

Comment: Sorry if I make you to edit the answer, I am really new into this. I learned a lot from your answer. Thank you very much once again!

Comment: Hi I got this kind ValueError but I think my input is already correct, How to solve this problem? @JohanC

ValueError: x and y arguments to pcolormesh cannot have non-finite values or be of type numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray with masked values

Comment: I already edit the post above with the newer problem.